# JSF: AJAX Testing best practices

Tags: java, ajax, unit-testing, jsf, jsf-2

We have a JSF 2.0 project with heavy use of AJAX (provided by OpenFaces tag library). Our project is very cool and does many useful things, and we love it. However there is one thing about it that frustrates us - our project doesn't have integration tests. At all. It has selenium tests of course, but they cover the project only from user's perspective. What I'd love to have are some integration tests which would deal with AJAX-related logic. But I'm not sure how to achieve this... Things that are capturing my mind are JSFUnit and HTTPUnit, but I wonder if there is something better for AJAX-based JSF project. Does anyone have any concerns about this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try FireUnit or FireBugTest. I haven't tried either of these but they might work. I have always wished for a feature like this too.

Comment: Great tools, I wonder if there a chance to plug them into maven

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Watir
http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Simple+Ajax+examples

It also has a firefox variant. FireWatir

--Kiran.Kumar